# How can i get my last clicked row of Jtable in java

Tags: java

I have a problem that i cann't get my last clicked row of Jtable in java.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What have you tried? How does your code look like? What kind of error/exception/unexpected behaviour are you getting? How do you expect anyone to help you without having the faintest idea of what your code looks like?

Comment: Have you even looked at the [JTable Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)?

Answer (score 1):

[Java API: JTable.getSelectedRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow())

> public int getSelectedRow()
>
> Returns the index of the first selected row, -1 if no row is selected.